# Failed to parse Adb version (Wrong ELF Class)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My PC CONFIGURATION :
`UBUNTU 11.10 version 64 bit ,
ECLIPSE 3.7 ,
ANDROID SDK`
 I tried hard to remove adb error but itsms not working and showing following Errors:

```
/platform-tools/adb:Error While loading Shared libraries
```

`libncurses.so.5:wrong ELF class:ELFCLASS64`

I even set all path for android set correctly but it wont works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elf (executable and link format) problem is due to your setup using amd64 and i386 stuff. The official Android SDK only runs on i386 JVM, so you need to manually specify the i386 JVM on Eclipse.

1. First install the <strike>Sun</strike>(Oracle) 32-bit JVM. [Here is](http://brunoreis.com/tech/intalling-java-ubuntu-natty/) a step-by-step on how to do this:
2. Add the JVM to Eclipse. Navigate:

   ```
   Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Add
   ```

   Put the location of the JVM. Probably will be `/usr/lib/jvm/java7/` (my is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun-1.7.0.01`). The external libraries will be *automatically* added when you put the location of the JVM.
    [image: Java7 Add Eclipse]
3. Set the <strike>Sun</strike> (Oracle) 32-bit JVM as default.
    [image: Java7 Default Eclipse]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is that you did not install 32 bit libraries that are required for Android. Try to delete eclipse, java, SDK and everything else connected with Android, run command:

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

And after that install everything from the beginning. Actually, before you can try just run this command, maybe this helps you.

Comment: i checked . It is available in my system

Comment: It can be available, but it can be 64-bit version. Google requires some libraries to be 32-bit. That's why you should install them.

Comment: It did help me. Ref: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#troubleshooting